# Some intuitive confusion on a basic math problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Rectangle $A = l \times w$, rectangle $B = 0.9l\times1.1w = (l-0.1l)(w+0.1w)$.

Clearly rectangle $A$ is larger, but if you take $w$ to infinity, $l$ to be extremely small approaching $0$, you should see that $A$ approaches $B$ such that $A = B$. However, the algebra shows that $B \times0.99 = A$ always. Shouldn't you see $A = B$ when you take the limit that $w\to\infty$ and $l\to 0$? I'm probably just confusing myself by using limits incorrectly here.

Comment: Have another little think about the algebra.

Comment: @dxiv Typo, I mean rectangle A

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Typo

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
B=0.99 l w = 0.99 A 
\end{eqnarray*}
?

Comment: If $\ell = 0$ then you have $A=B=0=0.99B$.  If $w$ "equals" $\infty$ then you would have $A$ and $B$ as well as $0.99B$ all "equalling $\infty$" as well, so no contradiction.

Comment: "Clearly rectangle A is larger, but if you take w to infinity, l to be extremely small approaching 0, you should see that A approaches B such that A=B."  Why is that your intuition?  It depends on the rate of approach.  Suppose $l$ always equals $\frac 1w$ then $A = 1$ and $\lim_{w,l\to \infty,0} A = 1$.  But if $l = \frac 1{w^2}$ then $A = \frac 1{w}$ and  $\lim_{w,l\to \infty,0} A = 0$.  Or if $l =\frac 1{\sqrt{w}}$ then $A = \sqrt{w}$ and $\lim_{w,l\to \infty,0} A = \infty$.  But it doesn't matter as $\lim B = \lim .99A$.  I honestly don't see how you think you can get $\lim A = B$.

Comment: But if you did come up with a way to get $\lim A = \lim B$ that's not a contradiction.  It just means $\lim A = \lim B = 0 = .990$ or $\lim A = \lim B = \infty = \lim .99 B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because two sequences have the same limit doesn't mean that their ratio is $1$, or even that the ratio has a limiting value of $1$.  Consider the two sequences

$$
\frac12, \frac14, \frac16, \frac18, \ldots
$$

$$
\frac13, \frac16, \frac19, \frac{1}{12}, \ldots
$$

They clearly both go to $0$ in the limit, but they are always in a 
$3:2$ ratio.

Comment: Worth noting that if $A_n = k*B_n; k \ne 0; k \ne 1$ and $\lim A_n = \lim B_n$ then either $\lim A_n = 0$ or $\lim A_n = \infty$.  If $\lim B_n = m$ and $m$ is a real number than $\lim A_n = \lim kB_n = m*k$.  If $m = m*k$ and then either $k=1$ or $m= 0$ or both.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one of the biggest issues here is you are trying to take two limits at the same time and return an indeterminate form.

If I have

$$\lim{x\to0},\;\lim{y\to\infty}\;xy$$

We have an indeterminate form. Also if two sums both go to either 0 or infinity, their ratios may not be one even in the limit despite going to the same number. $0.99\infty$ is still $\infty$ so even thought they would have the same value in the limit their ratios may not be 1.